# OS X prompts for password when connecting unencrypted volume and Disk Utility repair does not work

Tags: macos, ssd, filevault

I have an external 250 GB SSD which now, when I connect it (via USB) to the computer, causes the OS (10.10.3) to prompt me with:

> Enter a password to unlock the disk

The problem (well, *a* problem) is that the disk is not encrypted with FileVault. It does have an `encfs` filesystem on it, but that's in addition to regular non-encrypted files. So I don't know the password because there isn't one. (The encfs password does not work, when entered.)

Running Disk Utility's "repair volume" on the partition in question tells me that the journal needs to be replayed but the volume is read-only.

Is there a way for me to at least mount the filesystem read-only, ignoring the journal and taking my chances? I would of course ideally just like to repair the volume, so if that's an option then I'd love that.

Screenshot of the Disk Utility sidebar:

[image: Disk Utility sidebar (as requested)]

Output from `diskutil cs list` (added per request):

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group DF4A929C-B8A3-4617-BEC5-3EDA30BD727B
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         jarlawurra_new
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         479110004736 B (479.1 GB)
|   Free Space:   4096 B (4.1 KB)
|   |
|   +- Logical Volume Family 48E2E0AD-C14B-4498-BA47-CFA52AD2AE32
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
|       Conversion Status:       Complete
|       Conversion Direction:    -none-
|       Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
|       Fully Secure:            Yes
|       Passphrase Required:     Yes
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume B7E76DF2-D15E-4EBD-81BE-0E6F9FA39F0F
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk1
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          478774456320 B (478.8 GB)
|           Conversion Progress:   -none-
|           Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
|           LV Name:               jarlawurra
|           Volume Name:           jarlawurra
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 7389D19D-D87D-4FC7-AB83-D34D854F9FCF
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
    Free Space:   4096 B (4.1 KB)
    |
    +- Logical Volume Family AA5C01D8-ADE7-421F-A7E8-3DB26E6B621A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Locked
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            Yes
        Passphrase Required:     Yes
        |
        +-> Logical Volume F537746C-0EA1-409D-9E6D-FB9AC46E779C
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  -none-
            Status:                Locked
            Size (Total):          249804886016 B (249.8 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:               soto
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  935761728      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  936171368    1531680      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  937703048          7
  937703055         32         Sec GPT table
  937703087          1         Sec GPT header
```

And from `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2`, since /dev/disk1 seems to refer to the now-ejected aurex volume:

```
     start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488555536      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488965176    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the Disk Utility sidebar?

Comment: Done, edited question to include it.

Comment: Please eject the 4 TB aurex drive and add the output of  `diskutil cs list` as well as `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1` all entered in Terminal to your question

Comment: Done, and thank you for asking. I addded gpt output for /dev/disk2 since /dev/disk1 seems to still be a placeholder for the ejected aurex volume. I didn't know about either of those commands before!

Comment: @Jeremy Which of the two encfs implementations did you install? [EncFS](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/) or [EncFSMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/encfsmp/files/)

Comment: I have encfs installed via brew, which looks to be the former.